# Execute cmd.exe command (webpack) on windows with .NET Core and preserve colors and output

Tags: c#, webpack, command, .net-core, command-prompt

How can I execute cmd command (`webpack`) from .NET Core - console app and preserve colors?

This is my current code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dir = args.First();
    //build:vendor -> webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js --progress --color --display-error-details
    Console.WriteLine("npm run build:vendor -- --env.prod".Execute(dir));
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static string Execute(this string cmd, string startDir)
{
    var process = new Process()
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = $"/c {cmd}",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WorkingDirectory = startDir
        }
    };
    process.Start();
    string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();
    return result;
}
```

My output:
[image: current output]

Expected output:
[image: expected output]

I see 2 problems:
when I run command

- from cmd.exe, progress is displayed in percents but running command
  from dotnet outputs strange characters ...
- colors are missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshot it looks like your tool uses [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to format output. Those are character sequences which are interpreted by commands instead of regular text, by terminals that support them.

Before Windows 10, cmd.exe did not support such codes, instead requiring using specific winapi functions to control console text colors and other attributes. Starting with Windows 10 it is supported, but has to be enabled.

For example, suppose you do this:

```
Console.WriteLine("\x1b[35mHello World\x1b[0m");
```

By default it will print some nonsense similar to your current output. Now let's enable support for ANSI escape codes. For that we will need pinvoke to winapi function `SetConsoleMode`:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, uint dwMode);
```

And use some helper winapi functions:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, out uint lpMode);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);
```

Now we can enable required flag:

```
public class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
        // get handle to console output
        IntPtr hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        if (hOut != IntPtr.Zero) {
            uint mode;
            // get current mode
            if (GetConsoleMode(hOut, out mode)) {
                // add ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING flag which enables support for ANSI escape codes
                mode |= 0x0004; // ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING flag
                SetConsoleMode(hOut, mode);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\x1b[35mHello World\x1b[0m");            
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, uint dwMode);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, out uint lpMode);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);
}
```

If you run this on Windows 10, instead of some nonsense it should print "Hello World" in magentoo color to console output.

So, if you do this before writing redirected output - it should fix your problems.

Comment: Thank you @Evk. This is awesome. Can you just write how is support for windows server?

Comment: @Makla all I know is that was added in windows 10 (specific build number even), have no idea if it's supported on any version of windows server. You can of course just try and see how it goes.